# Is the locatation of channel file location specific?

Tags: facebook, sdk

Does the channel file need to be in the root of the site or may it reside in the directory that contains my canvas app pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can reside in the directory as long as you set the location correctly when you fb.init

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/